# Having issue with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have a few tables that I'm trying to join together, but I can't seem to figure out how to join them properly. Would anyone be able to help?  I want to specify both the attractionId and gradeId values, but I keep just getting nothing when I would have thought rows should be returned. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

I sqlfiddled it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2b03/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the first join to read:

```
INNER JOIN cirriculum_units ON cirriculum_units.cirriculumId = cirriculum_attractions.cirriculumId
```

instead of:

```
cirriculum_units.cirriculumId = cirriculum_attractions.attractionId
```

Comment: Ugh, I'm an idiot. I've been bashing my head against the wall for 2 hours now. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. Please mark as answered so it doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: Yep, will do as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

Your very first inner join has two fields in the on clause with no matching values.

Either the data is wrong or the wrong columns are named

Comment: It happens, sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes.

Comment: Haha, yeah, definitely needed fresh eyes :p